# extract xml information using vba

Tags: excel, xml, vba

I am trying to extract 2 bits of information from the following xml file using VBA but they seem really buried and can't seem to access them, I am very new to xml so this is a bit beyond me. I have found a number of examples on the web that I can make work using a simple xml file, but not this.

On the xml below I have tagged the two bits of information I need to pull out into a spreadsheet - the first one I need will form the header to a column, and then the second piece might occour a number of times below.

```
Sub ReadXML()
Call fnReadXMLByTags
End Sub
```

```
Function fnReadXMLByTags()
Dim mainWorkBook As Workbook
Set mainWorkBook = ActiveWorkbook
mainWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").Clear
Set oXMLFile = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
XMLFileName = "C:\Users\xxx\Documents\TestFile.xml"
oXMLFile.Load (XMLFileName)

Set slotNodes = oXMLFile.SelectNodes("/instrument/member/list/obj/member/string")
    
End Function
```

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<instrument>
   <string name="name" value="TEST" wide="true"/>   <!--I NEED TO EXTRACT THIS FIRST-->
   <member name="slotvisuals">
      <int name="ownership" value="1"/>
      <list name="obj" type="obj">
         <obj class="USlotVisuals" ID="882527840">
            <int name="displaytype" value="1"/>
            <int name="articulationtype" value="0"/>
            <int name="symbol" value="73"/>
            <string name="text" value="CUSTOM ART1" wide="true"/>
            <string name="description" value="CUSTOM ART1 DESCRIPTION" wide="true"/>
            <int name="group" value="0"/>
         </obj>
         <obj class="USlotVisuals" ID="45186017184">
            <int name="displaytype" value="1"/>
            <int name="articulationtype" value="0"/>
            <int name="symbol" value="73"/>
            <string name="text" value="GROUP 2" wide="true"/>
            <string name="description" value="GROUP 2" wide="true"/>
            <int name="group" value="1"/>
         </obj>
         <obj class="USlotVisuals" ID="882712304">
            <int name="displaytype" value="1"/>
            <int name="articulationtype" value="0"/>
            <int name="symbol" value="73"/>
            <string name="text" value="GROUP 3" wide="true"/>
            <string name="description" value="GROUP 3" wide="true"/>
            <int name="group" value="2"/>
         </obj>
         <obj class="USlotVisuals" ID="44402087248">
            <int name="displaytype" value="1"/>
            <int name="articulationtype" value="0"/>
            <int name="symbol" value="73"/>
            <string name="text" value="GROUP 4" wide="true"/>
            <string name="description" value="GROUP 4" wide="true"/>
            <int name="group" value="3"/>
         </obj>
      </list>
   </member>
   <member name="slots">
      <int name="ownership" value="1"/>
      <list name="obj" type="obj">
         <obj class="PSoundSlot" ID="2271687808">
            <obj class="PSlotThruTrigger" name="remote" ID="2276282784">
               <int name="status" value="144"/>
               <int name="data1" value="0"/>
            </obj>
            <obj class="PSlotMidiAction" name="action" ID="2268706176">
               <int name="version" value="600"/>
               <member name="noteChanger">
                  <int name="ownership" value="1"/>
                  <list name="obj" type="obj">
                     <obj class="PSlotNoteChanger" ID="2277009712">
                        <int name="channel" value="-1"/>
                        <float name="velocityFact" value="1"/>
                        <float name="lengthFact" value="1"/>
                        <int name="minVelocity" value="0"/>
                        <int name="maxVelocity" value="127"/>
                        <int name="transpose" value="0"/>
                        <int name="minPitch" value="0"/>
                        <int name="maxPitch" value="127"/>
                     </obj>
                  </list>
               </member>
               <member name="midiMessages">
                  <int name="ownership" value="1"/>
               </member>
               <int name="channel" value="-1"/>
               <float name="velocityFact" value="1"/>
               <float name="lengthFact" value="1"/>
               <int name="minVelocity" value="0"/>
               <int name="maxVelocity" value="127"/>
               <int name="transpose" value="0"/>
               <int name="maxPitch" value="127"/>
               <int name="minPitch" value="0"/>
               <int name="key" value="-1"/>
            </obj>
            <member name="sv">
               <int name="ownership" value="2"/>
               <list name="obj" type="obj">
                  <obj class="USlotVisuals" ID="909444640">
                     <int name="displaytype" value="1"/>
                     <int name="articulationtype" value="0"/>
                     <int name="symbol" value="73"/>
                     <string name="text" value="CUSTOM ART1" wide="true"/>
                     <string name="description" value="CUSTOM ART1 DESCRIPTION" wide="true"/>
                     <int name="group" value="0"/>
                  </obj>
                  <obj class="USlotVisuals" ID="43544745280">
                     <int name="displaytype" value="1"/>
                     <int name="articulationtype" value="0"/>
                     <int name="symbol" value="73"/>
                     <string name="text" value="GROUP 2" wide="true"/>
                     <string name="description" value="GROUP 2" wide="true"/>
                     <int name="group" value="1"/>
                  </obj>
                  <obj class="USlotVisuals" ID="44505641184">
                     <int name="displaytype" value="1"/>
                     <int name="articulationtype" value="0"/>
                     <int name="symbol" value="73"/>
                     <string name="text" value="GROUP 3" wide="true"/>
                     <string name="description" value="GROUP 3" wide="true"/>
                     <int name="group" value="2"/>
                  </obj>
                  <obj class="USlotVisuals" ID="44402092688">
                     <int name="displaytype" value="1"/>
                     <int name="articulationtype" value="0"/>
                     <int name="symbol" value="73"/>
                     <string name="text" value="GROUP 4" wide="true"/>
                     <string name="description" value="GROUP 4" wide="true"/>
                     <int name="group" value="3"/>
                  </obj>
               </list>
            </member>
            <member name="name">
               <string name="s" value="THIS IS SLOT 1" wide="true"/>   <!--AND THEN THIS-->
            </member>
            <int name="color" value="1"/>
         </obj>
      </list>
   </member>
   <member name="controller">
      <int name="ownership" value="1"/>
   </member>
</instrument>
```

Comment: You are using `"/catalog/member/list/obj/member/string"` but there is no catalog-node in your XML ...

Comment: Thanks - sorry - copied in an older version of the vba that I had been trying things with.

Comment: Still can’t get to the tags tho!

Comment: What happens when you run this code, and what are you trying to extract from the `string` node you have the comment beside? Do you want to get all attributes?

Comment: Not a lot happens with the code currently - but I’m not at my machine so can’t report. 

I’m trying to extract the text string that says “This Is Slot 1” and the text that says TEST.  The Test string will form the header on the excel sheet

Comment: A good way to figure out what is going on is to put a breakpoint in your code and add a watch for the `slotNodes` variable. Can help you see what type it is, and the different properties and methods of the variable.

Comment: 1) If you are sure that (only the indicated two) search expressions exist, you can simply code: `Debug.Print oXMLFile.SelectSingleNode("/instrument/string/@value").Text` to get *TEST* and `
`Debug.Print oXMLFile.SelectSingleNode("/instrument/member/list/obj/member/string/@value").Text` to get *THIS IS SLOT 1* :-) 2) Always declare your (object) variables, e.g. `Dim oXMLFile As Object`  3) I'd prefer `Set oXMLFile = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")` instead of *Microsoft.XMLDOM*. 4) `Call` is deprecated. 5) A function usually returns an assigned function value @Sub3OneDay

Comment: Thanks for all the comments! I've taken all this on board, and will post up the working code now. Really appreciate this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get what you are looking for in the query you already have (which worked for me). You should be able to use similar code to get the header, depending on how the query should go.

```
Function fnReadXMLByTags()
    Dim mainWorkBook As Workbook
    Set mainWorkBook = ActiveWorkbook
    mainWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").Clear
    Set oXMLFile = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
    XMLFileName = "C:\Users\xxx\Documents\TestFile.xml"
    oXMLFile.Load (XMLFileName)

    Set slotNodes = oXMLFile.SelectNodes("/instrument/member/list/obj/member/string")
    
    r = 2
    With mainWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    
        For Each slotNode In slotNodes
            .Cells(r, 1).Value = slotNode.getAttribute("value")
            r = r + 1
        Next slotNode        

    End With

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking all comments on board, and building on the answer by `@Professor Pantsless` above here is the working code.

```
Sub ReadXML()
Call fnReadXMLByTags
End Sub

Function fnReadXMLByTags()
    Dim mainWorkBook As Workbook
    Dim oXMLFile As Object
    
    Dim MapNameNode As Object
    Dim MapNameNodes As Object
    Dim slotNode As Object
    Dim slotNodes As Object
    Set oXMLFile = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")
    Set mainWorkBook = ActiveWorkbook
    
    mainWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").Clear

    XMLFileName = "C:\Users\xxx\Documents\TestFile.xml"
    oXMLFile.Load (XMLFileName)

    Set slotNodes = oXMLFile.SelectNodes("/InstrumentMap/member/list/obj/member/string")
    Set MapNameNodes = oXMLFile.SelectNodes("/InstrumentMap/string")
    
    
    r = 2
    
    With mainWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    For Each MapNameNode In MapNameNodes
            .Cells(1, 1).Value = MapNameNode.getAttribute("value")

        Next MapNameNode
    
        For Each slotNode In slotNodes
            .Cells(r, 1).Value = slotNode.getAttribute("value")
            r = r + 1
        Next slotNode

    End With

End Function
```

Comment: Keep in mind if this finds more than one match in `MapNameNodes` the final output will be the last one. This answer also uses the node `InstrumentMap` rather than `instrument`.

Comment: Thanks - yes - couldn’t seem to get it to work without using the For Each MapNameNode bit but that’s not a problem as there will always only be one of them. 
Noted about instrumentmap vs instrument - this reflects the actual xml files that I’m analysing - not the trial one I was testing the code on.